# can we integrate apple pay into any website?

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments, applepay

I am new to Apple Pay. I need to develop an website  in which I can integrate Apple Pay as an option. I have checked out official documentation of ApplePay for payment from the documents given on below link.

https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

They have mentioned that customer can pay to merchant for Service or goods.
But my question is can we integrate apple pay into any website?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to offer Apple Pay in your website at the moment. This is limited to iOS apps and stores for now as explained on their product [page](https://www.apple.com/apple-pay/):

> Paying in stores or within apps has never been easier.

Answer (score 2):

This will be supported in macOS when it is released in Autumn 2016, and is in the macOS beta released on June 13th 2016 at WWDC.

The documentation lacks any actual examples of how to integrate it as a whole at the moment, just the API definitions, which are very minimal.

A selection of links are below:

- [Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/)
- [Apple Pay JS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs)
- [Website Registration](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-domain-verification/)

An example integration of Apple Pay into a website can be found [here](https://github.com/justeat/ApplePayJSSample).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently investigating this integration. You can, but you need iOS native app as a wrapper and then you "project" a web view and call Objective C from javascript and vice versa.

You can find more about webkit bridge in the links bellow: 
Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf

Webkit bridge :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

Webkit example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CallJS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004241-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2